# Turn folder tree into file

Tags: file, compression, directory

How may I convert a folder, its subfolder and all containing files into a single contiguous file?

Bonus question: is flipping a file's bits considered a "1-bit encryption"?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: As a general rule, try to stick to one question at the time.